# Safari is caching local content - how do I stop this?

Tags: apache, caching, web, safari, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to OS X Mavericks it looks like Safari (or Chrome, or Firefox.. it seems to be a system level thing) is caching the website content. I do web development locally on my machine and when an update is pushed locally it doesn't translate to the browser when I refresh the page. Even clearing the cache through Develop > Empty Cache doesn't solve the problem. I'm on OS X Mavericks running MAMP.. any suggestions? I can't seem to find any help on Google either (just flooded with Mavericks reviews).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mamp read this. Need to comment out some lines and then it works.

http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=88120